# Changing the visibility of a sprite without changing it's position in the sprite group

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

I have two sprite groups: `visible_ui_elements` and `ui_elements`.  Only sprites that are in `visible_ui_elements` are rendered.  I am using the `set_visible` method to change the visibility of sprites.

```py
class UIMain:

    ui_elements = pg.sprite.Group()
    visible_ui_elements = pg.sprite.Group()


class UIComponent(pg.sprite.Sprite):

   def __init__(self):
       pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
 
       UIMain.visible_ui_elements.add(self)
       UIMain.ui_elements.add(self)

    def set_visible(self, visibility=False):
        """
        Changes the visibility of this component

        :param visibility: Set to true to make this component visible
        :return: None
        """
        if visibility:
            UIMain.visible_ui_elements.add(self)
        else:
            UIMain.visible_ui_elements.remove(self)
```

The problem I am having is that if a sprite was made invisible, but then later is made visible again, it's position in the sprite group is put to the front of that group, rather than where it was before.  This obviously causes the layering of sprites to be incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using the sprite group that manages drawing in layers. See the docs for `pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates` [here](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates).

The order of addition does not mater just the layer that the sprites are in. You can change the layer to move them up or down in the drawing order so the ones you want are on top.

The order you add them in the group would not matter then.